# Vote analysis for stackoverflow moderator election

Tags: discussion, data-analysis, election

I've analyzed the votes [based on the .blt file](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-results/)

```
                           User : [1st, 2nd, 3rd]
             ------------------------------------
             Robert C. Cartaino : [045, 061, 074]
                 George Stocker : [153, 170, 170]
                           Kyle : [207, 248, 211]
                           Will : [336, 231, 168]
               Jonathan Sampson : [330, 267, 233]
                    Jason Cohen : [350, 258, 221]
                    John Topley : [217, 159, 165]
               Jonathan Leffler : [321, 222, 189]
                         mmyers : [317, 211, 191]
                      John Rudy : [145, 144, 163]
                    Dave DeLong : [212, 164, 153]
                         Welbog : [198, 143, 157]
                         jjnguy : [129, 138, 145]
                            Kip : [121, 177, 167]
                          Gumbo : [408, 252, 231]
```

And here is the code I tried.

```
import re

d=open("stack-overflow-moderator-election-2010-votes.blt").read()
d=d.replace('"Stack Overflow Moderator Election 2010"',"")
d=re.sub("#.*?\n","",d)

votes,names=d.split("\n0\n")

votes=[map(int,x.split()) for x in re.findall("1 (.*) 0",votes)]
#[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2], [3, 2, 5], [3, 6, 7],

names=[{"name":n.strip('"'),"votes":[0,0,0]} for n in names.strip().split("\n")]
#[{'votes': [45, 61, 74], 'name': 'Robert C. Cartaino'},

for x in votes:
    if x:names[x.pop(0)-1]['votes'][0]+=1
    if x:names[x.pop(0)-1]['votes'][1]+=1
    if x:names[x.pop(0)-1]['votes'][2]+=1

lines=[" %30s : %s" % ("User","[1st, 2nd, 3rd]")]
lines.append(" "*13+"-"*36)

for x in names:
    lines.append(" %30s : %s"%(x['name'],x['votes']))

print "\n".join(lines)
```

Comment: Am I the only one thinking that some of Gumbo's votes are solely based on his gravatar? (not saying he didn't deserve it, mind you!)

Comment: possibly, but there also tends to be a correlation between high rep and votes as well, and Gumbo had the highest rep of all the candidates as I recall.

Comment: I've voted Gumbo 1st based on his contribution history btw.

Comment: @random, you mean someone missing? I only seen 15 people in .blt file

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. I just want to say thanks to everyone who voted for me -- to be honest, I expected to see my score have maybe (MAYBE) a dozen votes. :)

Comment: It was a fun run! Thanks to all who voted for me as well.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson, I have voted you in 2nd btw, and according to vote list, you are highest on 2nd

Comment: The only thing that really surprises me is the number of votes for Jason Cohen. I mean, based on his work outside SO, I think he'd be great -- but that's just it, I have to look *outside* SO to get an idea of what he's about. He seems to hardly ever visit SO anymore. http://stackoverflow.com/users/4926?tab=activity#tab-top shows two commments and one edit since *October*, and he hasn't visited since last week. But maybe I'm just paranoid and it'll all turn out fine. :)

Comment: Ironically, I've never heard of Gumbo (even though he's a really high reputation user). I didn't vote for Jason Cohen because he wasn't active in the site at all. I have no reason to believe that will change.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Some analysis of correlation between election results and some other stats (including SO rep) here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38879/some-statistics-from-the-stack-overflow-moderator-election-results

Comment: http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/9223/votes.png