# Tag cleanup feature: "public" list of questions with close votes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, closed-questions, clean-up

I believe I've seen proposals to show a list of questions with close votes (to **anyone** with close privileges) that were rejected due to fears of dog-piling (can't find them right now however). I'd like to suggest something narrower though: showing said list on a per-tag basis, as deemed necessary by the admins.

I'd envision someone posting a question here on meta suggesting a tag for intensive cleanup, the usual discussion and voting, and then the admins enabling such a list for that tag temporarily if they feel it's warranted. Perhaps it could be another tab under `review`, or a sidebar shown on questions with the targeted tag. Or if we're still *really* concerned about dog-piling, those questions could just be slipped back into the `review` queue without indicating why.

This would be a big help on my [quest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97958/help-me-defeat-the-barbarians-in-the-regex-tag) to clean up [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and Yi Jiang's quest to clean up [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). There are of course tons of dupes to be closed, along with a good deal of "too localized" and just plain incoherent questions. Copying each link and editing it into the question is a tedious process; with over 20,000 questions and counting it's a Sisyphean task. You've got to avoid duplicates in *that* list, remove links after questions are closed, and avoid trampling on each others edits.

A sidebar or review tab would make it a lot easier both to build the list, to get the right people looking at it, and to generally draw attention to these noble causes. With high-traffic tags that are popular with newcomers, this seems like the only way we can hope to really get things under control.

It's also got built-in rate limiting since it's tied to close votes, and if we want further protection against invalid closings, questions with the targeted tag which are closed during the intensive cleanup could also be put back into the review cue since we'd know which tag is being targeted.

Comment: Uh, am I missing something? I thought we already had that... Click the ["close" tab in the 10k tools](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close). You can expand the drop-down arrows by clicking on them for either "Most Votes" or "Recent Votes", and even choose a time frame.

Comment: Yep.  But @bemace isn't a 10K.  He's requesting it for normal users (like me) to improve the reviewing process.

Comment: probably it would be simpler if you ran for SO Moderator. Unfortunately there is a [depressingly large correlation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38879/some-statistics-from-the-stack-overflow-moderator-election-results) between "votes to be a moderator" and "reputation on SO".. sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [close review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1356464) is available to everyone who can vote to close *and* allows you to filter by tag.

Comment: Although you can filter the close review queue by tag, it only shows the questions with close votes that _you_ have not voted on yet. That's not the same as seeing all the questions with close votes.