# Suggestion for a new badge: the Headscratcher

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New badge for questions with a high number of views, high number of votes and no answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42647/new-badge-for-questions-with-a-high-number-of-views-high-number-of-votes-and-no)

A question that gets at least X (5? 10? 20?) upvotes before getting the first answer (accepted or not).

Maybe...

- Bronze: Headscratcher (5 votes before answer)
- Silver: Headbanger (10 votes before answer)
- Gold: Headexploder (20 votes before answer)

Comment: Gold: Headasploder

Comment: I really like the idea!

Comment: BTW, different people scratch different parts of their body while thinking.